# Short story where AI needs humans to collapse reality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have tried searching here and elsewhere and cannot find this short story. Here are the details I can remember:

- General AI exists but it can't operate when humans aren't around.
- The AI figures out that it needs humans to observe reality in order to make reality more real.
- When humans aren't around, the AI is stuck in some kind of void without the sensation of time and they hate it.
- AIs wage war against the humans by capturing them and attaching them to their frame so they can observe reality.
- The AIs test extensively to figure out the minimum viable product that counts as "human" so reality can be observed.
- They end up with things that are basically just brain stems and eyes.
- This "humans" are kept in fluid-filled glass chambers all over the outside of the AIs so they can observe reality.
- Somewhere out in an asteroid field is a mother and her child in a derelict ship, living in the few remaining pressurized sections. (Maybe the ship was a hollowed out asteroid or something.)
- The mother is building some machine to transfer her son's consciousness into an older mining robot.
- The son plays with a "doll" the mother made by bending wire into a stick figure.
- There's an AI hunting them within the asteroid field by looking for signs of life which include objects spinning at the right speed to sustain humans.

At the conclusion of the story:

> • The hunting AI finds them and starts heading over.
>  • The machine works and transfers the child's brain into the older robot.
>  • The child/robot fights the AI and wins.
>  • The mother leaves to get something and, when she gets back, she realizes that, while she was gone, her child/robot was in that timeless void that the AIs experience when humans aren't observing.

Comment: When and where did you read this?  Was it online, in an anthology or in a magazine?  How long was it (short story or novella)?

Comment: I've read this quite recently. The description here is excellent

Comment: @Valorum Yes, exactly! I couldn't find it in my searches. I'll close this question as duplicate.

Comment: @EngineerToast - [Happy to have helped](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)